# How to wait for 3 mints if the n/w got disconnected while copying in Rsync without failing using perl script?

Tags: networking, rsync, perl

I have to transfer 2-3 GB using Rsync.Everything is working fine, but my network got disconnected sometimes, and the entire process got failed.
I want to retry it for the network for every 3 mints, and once if network came back copying should continue. I am planning to write it in Perl script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this needs to have anything to do with Perl. I mean, you just want to continue running rsync - a command line application - if it fails. Wouldn't something like this suffice?

```
while ! rsync -a /mydir myuser@remotehost:/other_dir; do
    sleep 180;
done
```

### Explanation

This will keep trying to run the `rsync` command until it successfully completes (with an exit code of 0). In every iteration it will wait 180 seconds before continuing. This is all bash script, btw, and will run unmodified in your terminal.

### In perl

I have never written Perl, but since you requested a perl version, I have hacked together this using Google and the Perl interpreter in a few minutes ...

```
my $rsync = 'rsync -a /mydir myuser@remotehost:/other_dir';

while ( system($rsync) == -1 ) { 
    sleep 180;
}
```

Save as `sync.pl` and run with `perl sync.pl`. Of course, substitute the directory and hostnames for real values.